# twilio sms is not being delivered to target phone numberbut its status is sent in my twilio account log

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I am using Twilio to send SMS to targeted phone numbers in my web app(which I am developing in asp.net). Twilio SMS is not being delivered to target phone numbers but its status is sent in my twilio account log. One more thing, when I send SMS to the number on which I activate my twilio account, message is delivered to that phone number. Can anyone please help me to sort out this?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. If you are making the API calls correctly but messages aren't being sent, I would contact support on help@twilio.com. If you can supply some Message SIDs that haven't been sent, that would be particularly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who view my question. I solved the problem my self. The issue was by default twilio didn't allowed service for programmable SMS. I checked it to allow to get SMS and voice calls on all numbers.

Comment: Great start Mr. @tanveerAshraf . :-) . It works fine and keep it up

Comment: @tanveer i am facing the same issue in Twilio logs it is showing the message status delivered but i am not receiving the message on my phone. Can you please explain it a bit how you resolved this issue?  thanks

Comment: It is because if you have free account, then twilio allows only 1 number which can receive messages. In your code, your receiving number must be yours, otherwise you need to have a paid account.

Comment: One more thing, the number should be in E164 format.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this same issue but I've managed to resolve it by removing additional verified phone numbers (i.e. you need only 1 with the trial account).